# How can I find a lost Samsung Device?

Tags: mobile, samsung-galaxy

I have lost my phone. Device is logged to Google account, has Find My Device enabled and is also logged to Samsung account and has SmartThings Find enabled.

If I log into Google's Find My Device app website, it thinks for a while and then announces that it can't contact the device. It doesn't show last known location.

If I try to log into Samsung SmartThings Find website, it errors out:
[image]